# How to send email from Outlook with inline image using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, charts, outlook

I am writing code for pasting the range `A11:K82` to the Outlook message  body, including tables and charts.  I need to paste it in **editable** format. I have completed coding for that but my graphs have not been displayed.

Please help me to complete.

```
Sub Mail()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Worksheets("SS Night Letter").Activate
    subb = Range("b11").Value
    Set rng = Nothing

    ' Only send the visible cells in the selection.
    Worksheets("Distribution List").Activate
    distlist = Range("c3").Value
    Worksheets("SS Night Letter").Activate

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    With OutMail
        .to = distlist
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = subb
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        .Display
    End With

    On Error GoTo 0
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
    ' By Ron de Bruin
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook
    mm = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".html"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        Workbooks(mm).Activate
        Range("A11:K81").Select
        Selection.Copy
        TempWB.Activate
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
            SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
            Filename:=TempFile, _
            Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
            Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
            HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
        "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile
    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing

End Function
```

[image: img]

Please support me to solve this.

Comment: What is your *specific* problem?  What isn't working, and what have you tried? Are you getting an error, and if s, where?  There are numerous examples, on this site and others, of how to send emails with images either inline or as attachments, using VBA, which have you tried?  (See the [help/on-topic] as well as "[mcve]".)

Comment: hi don't have any issue in coding my problem is only my excel chart is not visible in outlook

Comment: You DO have a problem in your coding if your coding isn't giving you the result you want. Have you investigated whether Excel VBA will consider the chart a shape and how to paste shapes?